# git - working with multiple repositories - but fetching changes not appearing

Tags: git, version-control

I'm using git to work with multiple repositories. To fetch and push to my repository on bitbucket and to only fetch from a public repository in github:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:user/example.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:user/example.git (push)
template        https://github.com/user/egrepo.git (fetch)
template        git://github.com/user/egrepo.git (push)
```

However when I try to fetch from the github repo, even though it seems to pick up those changes I can't seem to find them anywhere:

```
$ git fetch template
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3476, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
remote: Total 3476 (delta 27), reused 2 (delta 0), pack-reused 3417
Receiving objects: 100% (3476/3476), 649.77 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2114/2114), done.
From https://github.com/user/repo
 * [new branch]      1.6        -> template/1.6
 * [new branch]      master     -> template/master
 * [new branch]      pr/154     -> template/pr/154
 * [new branch]      remove-duplicate-styles -> template/remove-duplicate-styles
 * [new branch]      update-hitch-requirements -> template/update-hitch-requirements
 * [new tag]         0.1.0      -> 0.1.0
 * [new tag]         1.6.6      -> 1.6.6
 * [new tag]         1.7.7      -> 1.7.7
```

However I don't see those changes appear locally (Note I only have one branch currently):

```
$git branch 
* master
```

Comment: `git branch` only shows local branches by default.  Use `git branch -r` to see "remote" (aka remote-tracking) branches, or `git branch -a` to see all branches (both local and remote).

Comment: Thanks that's very useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch` only updates the local repo's index - it lets the local repo know that other commits and branches exist, but it does not update the code itself. You either need to run `git fetch` then `git merge`, or just do `git pull` which does both.